# String in Java Arithmetic (evaluating mixed type expression)

Tags: java, string, math

How would I answer a question such as "what does the below expression evaluate to".

```
"2 + 2 " + 3 + 4;
```

because I'm having a really hard time on the website practice-it and have tried everything from **2234** to **11** as possible answers.

Comment: may be 29? ("2 + 2" = 22, 22 + 3 + 4 = 29) However doesn't seem to be a real SO suitable question.

Comment: Have you tried putting into a java program, compile and then run to see the answer?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you explain this to me more clearly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java if either side of an addition is a string, the non-string operand is converted to a string and the two strings are concatenated. Never will a string be converted to an integer by using addition. Nor will a string containing an integer expression ever be evaluated.

So since addition is left-associative `"2 + 2 " + 3 + 4` is parsed as `("2 + 2 " + 3) + 4`, which will evaluate to `"2 + 2 3" + 4`, which will in turn evaluate to `"2 + 2 34"`.

Comment: how would i do this now... 2 + " 2 + 3 " + 4

Comment: See if you can work it out yourself using the procedure that @sepp2k used.  (You should get "2 2 + 3 4")

Comment: i figured it out eventually, extremely happy i found this site.

Comment: how would i do this, sorry if i seem like a nuissance
2 + "(int) 2.0" + 2 * 2 + 2

Comment: @Vonage93 The fact that the contents of the string don't matter should hopefully be clear now. So the only question is how to handle the `*`. For this you should recall the operator precedence of `+` vs. `*`. I.e. ask yourself: how does `a + b * c + d` generally get evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

"2 + 2 " + 3 + 4 is a String in Java and is equals to "2 + 2 34".

Comment: -1: Did you try actually actually putting it into code?  This is in fact incorrect.

Comment: Yes, just edited. I answered off the top of my head, then executed it out of curiosity. My apologies

Comment: `("2+2" + 3 + 4) is 2+234` `("2 + 2" + 3 + 4) is 2 + 234` - watch white spaces!

Comment: I think there is a white space. Not that it matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the character string into its components, then interpret those components, just as if you were writing an expression interpreter (which you are).